# Trimming data and separating it simultaneously - xcode

Tags: objective-c, arrays, xcode

The following code can trim my data from a textfield (remove spaces) and it can separate the data into an array, but I can't figure out how to do both at the same time. The code only works if I do one thing at a time:

```
NSArray *array = [self.textField.text componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@","]];
```

and

```
NSArray *array = [self.textfield.text stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]]
```

How can I do both of these things to the same array at the same time?
Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create your own character set with a space and a comma:

```
NSCharacterSet * characterSet = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@", "];
```

Then

```
NSArray * array = [self.textfield.text componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:characterSet];
```

update : (I haven't tested this)
If you end up with empty @" " strings in your array, you could remove them from the array like this  :

```
NSMutableArray * array = [[self.textfield.text componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:characterSet] mutableCopy];

[array removeObject:@" "];
```

Comment: Thank you! I do get the warning "Incompatible pointer types initializing NSArray with an expression type of NSString"

Comment: sorry, should be - componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:

Comment: Thanks, that works! Only problem is additional white spaces are saved in the array.